# Ruby-AWS where to save config / how to load config

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I am not sure what is the best way to do an appliaction wide configuration of the [Ruby/Aws](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-aws/) gem?

I found an example of how a configuration file needs to look like: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=117931#117931

But what is the recommended way to store the configuration? Shall I put a simple file in config/amazonrc
and then call

```
Amazon::Config.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazonrc")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found now a good solution:

**config/initializers/amazon.rb**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment.rb'    
ENV['AMAZONRCDIR'] = "#{Rails.root}/config/"
```

**config/.amazonrc**

```
[global]
locale = 'de'
cache = false
key_id = '0Y44V8FAFNM119C6PXX2'
secret_key_id = 'YYYYYY'

[de]
associate = 'ID-21'
```